# Automate SSL FTP upload via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ssl, webclient, ftpwebrequest

I have searched and read a lot about downloading *SSL FTP* files in PowerShell... But how do I upload them? I have a filename I need to upload each day and I get errors that I am not logged in.
I'm currently uploading to other FTP sites like this:

```
$Filename = "myfile.txt"
$FullPath = "\\server\share\$Filename"
$ftp = "ftp://user:pass@ftp.domain.com/$Filename"
$ftpWebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$ULuri= New-Object System.URI($ftp)
$ftpWebClient.UploadFile($ULuri, $FullPath)
```

Do I need to create a whole new block of code for the *SSL FTP* upload, or do I just need to make minor adjustments to this code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I use the WinSCP DLL to do this stuff.  Check out some examples here:
http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library#powershell

Here's some of my sample code.

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("D:\WinSCP.dll") | Out-Null
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions
$sessionOptions.Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
$sessionOptions.HostName = "192.168.1.120"
$sessionOptions.UserName = "user"
$sessionOptions.Password = "pass"
$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
$session.Open($sessionOptions)

#upload stuff here, check the link for detail on how, and use powershell to populate your file list!

$session.Dispose()
```

Comment: SFTP is not FTP over TLS/SSL. For FTP over TLS/SSL use `$sessionOptions.Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Ftp` and `$sessionOptions.FtpSecure = [WinSCP.FtpSecure]::Explicit`

Comment: Just to add to @MartinPrikryl's comment, you will also need to either set `$sessionOptions.GiveUpSecurityAndAcceptAnyTlsHostCertificate = $true` or set `$sessionOptions.TlsHostCertificateFingerprint = "00:11:22:..."`

Comment: @Mort You need that only if the server's certificate is not signed by a trusted authority.

Answer (score 6):

As you are already using the WebClient class from the .NET framework in your script, I suggest you create a derived version from WebClient that supports FTP over TLS, by embedding C# code in PowerShell:

```
$typeDefinition = @"
using System;
using System.Net;
public class FtpClient : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        FtpWebRequest ftpWebRequest = base.GetWebRequest(address) as FtpWebRequest;
        ftpWebRequest.EnableSsl = true;
        return ftpWebRequest;
    }
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $typeDefinition
$ftpClient = New-Object FtpClient
$ftpClient.UploadFile("ftp://your-ftp-server/yourfile.name", "C:\YourLocalFile.name")
```